# Get world position from Fragment Depth

Tags: mathematics, glsl, glm

I am trying to write the depth value in a G-buffer pass and then read it later to determine the world-space location of a fragment.

I have this shader which renders my G-buffer pass

```
#version 330
// #extension GL_ARB_conservative_depth : enable
// out vec4 fColor[2];
// INITIAL_OPAQUE.FS
// layout (depth_greater) out float gl_FragDepth;
// ^ should probably re-enable that later

//List of flags. Some of these are no longer implemented, they caused too much of a performance problem. I do not recommend you enable them.
const uint GK_RENDER = uint(1); // Do we render it? This is perhaps the most important flag.
const uint GK_TEXTURED = uint(2); // Do we texture it? if disabled, only the texture will be used. if both this and colored are disabled, the object will be black.
const uint GK_COLORED = uint(4);// Do we color it? if disabled, only the texture will be used. if both this and textured are disabled, the object will be black.
const uint GK_FLAT_NORMAL = uint(8); // Do we use flat normals? If this is set, then the normals output to the fragment shader in the initial opaque pass will use the flat layout qualifier. 
const uint GK_FLAT_COLOR = uint(16); // Do we render flat colors? the final, provoking vertex will be used as the color for the entire triangle.
const uint GK_COLOR_IS_BASE = uint(32); //Use the color as the primary. Uses texture as primary if disabled.
const uint GK_TINT = uint(64); //Does secondary add to primary?
const uint GK_DARKEN = uint(128);//Does secondary subtract from primary?
const uint GK_AVERAGE = uint(256);//Do secondary and primary just get averaged?
const uint GK_COLOR_INVERSE = uint(512);//Do we use the inverse of the color?
const uint GK_TEXTURE_INVERSE = uint(1024);//Do we use the inverse of the texture color? DOES NOT invert alpha.
const uint GK_TEXTURE_ALPHA_MULTIPLY = uint(2048);//Do we multiply the color from the texture by the alpha before doing whatever it is we're doing? I do not recommend enabling this and alpha culling, especially if you're trying to create a texture-on-a-flat-color-model effect (Think sega saturn models)
const uint GK_ENABLE_ALPHA_CULLING = uint(4096); //Do we use the texture alpha to cull alpha fragments
const uint GK_TEXTURE_ALPHA_REPLACE_PRIMARY_COLOR = uint(8192); //if the alpha from the texture is <0.5 then the secondary color will replace the primary color.


//Utility functions
// vec4 when_eq(vec4 x, vec4 y) {
  // return 1.0 - abs(sign(x - y));
// }

// vec4 when_neq(vec4 x, vec4 y) {
  // return abs(sign(x - y));
// }

// vec4 when_gt(vec4 x, vec4 y) {
  // return max(sign(x - y), 0.0);
// }

// vec4 when_lt(vec4 x, vec4 y) {
  // return max(sign(y - x), 0.0);
// }

// vec4 when_ge(vec4 x, vec4 y) {
  // return 1.0 - when_lt(x, y);
// }

// vec4 when_le(vec4 x, vec4 y) {
  // return 1.0 - when_gt(x, y);
// }




uniform sampler2D diffuse; //This is actually the texture unit. limit 32. This one happens to be for the literal object's texture.
uniform samplerCube worldaroundme; //This is the cubemap we use for reflections.

in vec2 texcoord;
in vec3 normout;
flat in vec3 flatnormout;
flat in vec3 Flat_Vert_Color;
in vec3 Smooth_Vert_Color;
in vec3 ND_out;
in vec2 window_size;
in vec3 vert_to_camera;
in vec2 accompanyinginfo;
in float ourdepth;
//Logic from the vertex level
in float isFlatNormal;
in float isTextured;
in float isColored;
in float isFlatColor;
in float ColorisBase;
in float AlphaReplaces;
in float isTinted;
in float isDarkened;
in float isAveraged;
in float isNotAnyofThose;
in float Wcomponent; //Opengl Forums guy thinks we might need this!


uniform float ambient;
uniform float specreflectivity;
uniform float specdamp;
uniform float emissivity;
uniform float jafar;
uniform float janear;
uniform float enableCubeMapReflections;
uniform float diffusivity;

vec2 bettertexcoord;
vec4 texture_value;
vec3 color_value;
vec3 primary_color;
vec3 secondary_color;
vec3 finalcolor = vec3(0,0,0); //default value. Does it work?
uniform uint renderflags;

void main()
{
    bettertexcoord = vec2(texcoord.x, -texcoord.y); //Looks like blender
    vec3 UnitNormal;
    vec3 usefulNormal;



    UnitNormal = ((normalize(flatnormout) + vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0)) * 0.5)* float((renderflags & GK_FLAT_NORMAL) > uint(0))+ ((normalize(normout) + vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0)) * 0.5) * (1-float((renderflags & GK_FLAT_NORMAL) > uint(0)));

    // if (UnitNormal.x > 1 || UnitNormal.y > 1 || UnitNormal.z > 1)
        // UnitNormal = vec3(1.0);

    usefulNormal = normalize(flatnormout) * float((renderflags & GK_FLAT_NORMAL) > uint(0)) + normalize(normout) * (1-float((renderflags & GK_FLAT_NORMAL) > uint(0)));



    texture_value = (texture2D(diffuse, bettertexcoord)) * float((renderflags & GK_TEXTURED) > uint(0)) + vec4(0.0,0.2,0.0,1.0) * (1-float((renderflags & GK_TEXTURED) > uint(0)));

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //UNCOMMENT THIS LINE IF YOU WANT ALPHA CULLING! It will slow down your application, be weary!
    // if ((renderflags & GK_ENABLE_ALPHA_CULLING) > uint(0))
        // if (texture_value.w == 0)
            // discard;
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


    //Color stuff
    // if ((renderflags & GK_FLAT_COLOR & GK_COLORED) > uint(0))
    // {
            // color_value = Flat_Vert_Color;
    // } else {
        // if ((renderflags & GK_COLORED) > uint(0))
        // {
            // color_value = Smooth_Vert_Color;
        // } else {
            // color_value = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        // }
    // }
    float flat_color = float((renderflags & GK_FLAT_COLOR) > uint(0));
    float colored_at_all = float((renderflags & GK_COLORED) > uint(0));

    color_value = flat_color * colored_at_all * Flat_Vert_Color + (1-flat_color) * colored_at_all * Smooth_Vert_Color + (1-flat_color) * (1-colored_at_all) * vec3(0,0,0);

    //primary_color and secondary_color stuff

    // if ((renderflags & GK_COLOR_IS_BASE) > uint(0))
    // {
        // primary_color = color_value;
        // secondary_color = texture_value.xyz;
    // } else {
        // primary_color = texture_value.xyz;
        // secondary_color = color_value;
    // }
    float colorbase = float((renderflags & GK_COLOR_IS_BASE) > uint(0));

    primary_color = colorbase * color_value + (1-colorbase) * texture_value.xyz;
    secondary_color = (1-colorbase) * color_value + colorbase * texture_value.xyz;

     // if ((renderflags & GK_TEXTURE_ALPHA_REPLACE_PRIMARY_COLOR) > uint(0))
     // {
         // extremely clever programming results in perfect effect...
        // primary_color = (primary_color * (1-texture_value.w)) + (texture_value.xyz * texture_value.w);
     // }


    float alphareplace = float((renderflags & GK_TEXTURE_ALPHA_REPLACE_PRIMARY_COLOR) > uint(0));
    primary_color = primary_color * (1-alphareplace) + (primary_color * (1-texture_value.w)) + (texture_value.xyz * texture_value.w) * alphareplace;
    //EQUATION TIME!

    //This will be hell to break up. Maybe the compiler will do it for me?
    // if ((renderflags & GK_TINT) > uint(0))
        // finalcolor = primary_color + secondary_color;
    // else if ((renderflags & GK_DARKEN) > uint(0))
        // finalcolor = primary_color - secondary_color;
    // else if ((renderflags & GK_AVERAGE) > uint(0))
        // finalcolor = vec3(
        // (primary_color.x + secondary_color.x)/2.0,
        // (primary_color.y + secondary_color.y)/2.0,
        // (primary_color.z + secondary_color.z)/2.0);
    // else
        // finalcolor = primary_color;

    //Floating point logic tables?!?! 
    float isTint = float((renderflags & GK_TINT) > uint(0)); // 1 if true, 0 if false
    float isNotTint = 1-isTint;//swaps with the other value
    float isDarken = float((renderflags & GK_DARKEN) > uint(0));
    float isNotDarken = 1-isDarken;
    float isAverage = float((renderflags & GK_AVERAGE) > uint(0));
    float isNotAverage = 1-isAverage;
    //it is none of those if:
    //* More than one of them is true
    //* All of them are false
    float isNoneofThose = isTint * isDarken * isAverage + isNotTint * isAverage * isDarken + isTint * isNotAverage * isDarken + isTint * isAverage * isNotDarken + isNotTint * isNotAverage * isNotDarken;
    float isNotNoneofThose = 1-isNoneofThose;

    //Calc finalcolor;
    finalcolor = (primary_color + secondary_color) * isTint * isNotNoneofThose + (primary_color - secondary_color) * isDarken * isNotNoneofThose + vec3((primary_color.x + secondary_color.x)/2.0,(primary_color.y + secondary_color.y)/2.0,(primary_color.z + secondary_color.z)/2.0) * isAverage * isNotNoneofThose + primary_color * isNoneofThose;



    // (diffuse component * texture) + specular
    // gl_FragData[0] = mix(vec4(finalcolor,specreflectivity),vec4(texture(worldaroundme,reflect(-vert_to_camera, usefulNormal)).xyz, specreflectivity),specreflectivity/2.0); //Lol
    vec4 cubemapData = texture(worldaroundme,reflect(-vert_to_camera, usefulNormal));
    gl_FragData[0] = vec4(mix(finalcolor, cubemapData.xyz, specreflectivity * enableCubeMapReflections),specreflectivity);


    gl_FragData[1] = vec4(UnitNormal,specdamp/128.0); //Normals. Specular dampening goes as high as 128 in OpenGL Immediate Mode, so it has to be allowed up there. Note that we are using 16 bit floating-point accuracy, so dividing will not seriously reduce our abilities with regards to specdamp

    //INTENSE DEBUGGING OF FRAG DEPTH
    // if ((ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear) >= 0 && (ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear)<= 1.0)
    // {
        gl_FragData[2] = vec4((ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear), diffusivity, (Wcomponent+128)/256, emissivity/2.0 + 0.5); //Masked with Emissivity
    // }
    // else if ((ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear) < 0)
    // {
        // gl_FragData[2] = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    // } else if ((ourdepth+janear)/(jafar+janear) > 1.0){
        // gl_FragData[2] = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    // }
}
```

Then I have this other shader which is intended to render my Point Light pass

```
#version 330
out vec4 fColor[2];

in vec2 texcoord;
in vec2 ScreenPosition;
// uniform sampler2D diffuse; //This is actually the texture unit. limit 32. This one happens to be for the literal object's texture.

uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;
uniform sampler2D tex3;
uniform vec3 position;
uniform vec3 color;
uniform float range;
uniform float range_dropoff;
uniform float jafar;
uniform float janear;
uniform mat4 invCamMatrix; //Passes in the camera matrix but inverted!
void main()
{
    //Save the values from the initial opaque pass.
    vec4 tex1_value = texture2D(tex1, texcoord);
    vec4 tex2_value = texture2D(tex2, texcoord);
    vec4 tex3_value = texture2D(tex3, texcoord);
    //Grab Emissivity
    float emissivity = (tex3_value.w - 0.5) * 2.0;
    float dist_cameraspace = (tex3_value.x * (jafar+janear))- janear; //Cameraspace distance from the point. I believe this works.
    //vec4 loc_fragspace; //Unadjusted fragment spacec
    float Wcomponent = (tex3_value.z * 256) - 128;//W component is stored in Z. it definitely does something...
    vec4 loc_cameraspace = vec4(ScreenPosition.x,ScreenPosition.y,dist_cameraspace, Wcomponent); //Cameraspace location
    // loc_cameraspace = vec4(loc_cameraspace.xyz*loc_cameraspace.w,loc_cameraspace.w);
    vec4 loc_world = invCamMatrix * loc_cameraspace; //World Location of the fragment. We are having issues here.
    //Some dude on the opengl forums said this would help
    // loc_world = vec4(loc_world.xyz/loc_world.w, loc_world.w);
    float diffusivity = tex3_value.y; //PHONG related value
    float masked = float(tex3_value.w == 0); //We are masking in emissivity. THIS WORKS.
    vec3 surface_normal = (tex2_value.xyz * 2) - vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    float specular_dampening = tex2_value.w * 128.0;
    float specular_reflectivity = tex1_value.w;

    //Now let's calculate the vector from the frag to the light
    vec3 frag_to_light = position - loc_world.xyz;
    float distance_from_light = length(frag_to_light.xyz);
    frag_to_light = normalize(frag_to_light);



    //Now that we have all the information from the Initial Opaque pass, let's get to PHONG!
    //Calculate Light direction
    vec3 lightDir = -frag_to_light;
    //Calculate nDotL
    float nDotL = max(dot(surface_normal, frag_to_light),0.0);
    //Find the diffuse value.
    vec3 betterdiffuse = nDotL * color * (1-masked);
    //Find the reflection vector.
    vec3 reflectedLightDir = reflect(lightDir, surface_normal);

    //fColor[0] = (loc_world + vec4(512)) * 1/1024 *  (1-masked);
    fColor[0] = vec4(surface_normal,1.0) * (1-masked);
    fColor[1] = tex2_value;
}
```